# Bootstrap responsive typography for desktop and mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, sass, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get my Bootstrap 4 font size settings right so that my web application looks good on mobile devices, like phones or tablets, and desktop systems, like any Linux, Mac, Windows with Chrome or Firefox installed. Now, everywhere I read about responsive typography, manuals talk about an *easy process*, but I honestly find it quite difficult to get it look like I need as I am still fairly new to SASS and Bootstrap 4.

I copied the setting from the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#responsive-typography) and this is the result in my web application's main SASS (style/app.global.scss) file:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    html {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

The default font size for Bootstrap 4 is 16px on the `<html>` element, which is ok. On my phone though (Samsung Galaxy s8) 16px is barely readable due to the dense pixels per square inch. So I moved it up `3rem`. Until here, the behavior is as expected.

But there is the unwanted side-effect that if I reduce my Chrome browser window on my MacBook Pro to a smaller width than `992px`, the mobile size of `3rem` kicks in and I have huge letters.

What I would like to achieve though, is to always have the same font size of `16px` on the desktop and to not jump to the bigger font size when making the browser window smaller.

Is there a way to distinguish between mobile and desktop devices in general? The Bootstrap 4 docs look great on mobile and desktop and if I reduce the Chrome browser window to a smaller width, the letters still remain within the same size. Is there a special command for that in SASS?

The index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello React!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the index.tsx:

```
import "bootstrap";
import "./style/app.global.scss";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Site } from "./components/Site";
import { Title } from "./components/Title";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Title titleName="MySite" />,
    document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Site siteName="MySite" />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions.

(1) As a general rule, if you are wanting responsive font sizes, consider using the viewport width unit of **vw** for the font size, if you do this the font size will scale with the viewport or window size.

And to compensate for the font getting too small on mobile, use calc() to essentially add a minimum font size

Here's an example:
CSS

```
html { font-size: calc(1em + 1vw); }
```

[view this live](https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/MzpYOx)

In this example I've applied the sizing to the html element, you could of course apply something similar just to the headings or other selectors on the page.

(2) As for the specific issue you described of the font getting too small on your phone, my first suspicion is that the reason is because you have forgotten to include a viewport meta tag in the head of your doc. Please try something like this and see if it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Hello React!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, David! Adding the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` solved everything. Nice to know that this is another influencing area. One never learns out! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do this and I will show two ways here.

First one and is probably the most preferred one. Use media queries:

```
    /* Small devices (Phones, 600pxand down) -- this would display the text at 5.0rem on phones */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 5.0rem; // you can also use px here...
    }
}


/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) -- This would display the text at 10.0rem on laptops and larger screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 10.0rem; // you can also use px here...
    }
}
```

The other option - it pretty much just scales up and down your text:

```
h1{
 font-size: 10vw;
}
```